# Cómo reemplazar la coma por un punto en una cadena que está entre comillas

Tags: batch

Tengo cadenas que están separadas por comas y está entre comillas pero tengo un problema en algunas cadenas y es que contiene comas, quiero reemplazar las comas por los puntos que están dentro de las comillas.

La siguiente cadena es la que quiero analizar y remplazar la coma:

> = "4559831579632915", 455983, = "00", = "4121", "Uber, PAÍSES BAJOS (NL)", "help.uber.com"

La salida debería ser así:

> = "4559831579632915", 455983, = "00", = "4121", "Uber. NETHERLANDS (NL)", "help.uber.com"

Comment: Hola Adrían, **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**, por favor [edit] y traduce tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave He traducido, a ver si revisa la edición. Igual iba a pregunta en la página en inglés y se ha equivocado.

Comment: @Lorthas, gracias por traducirlo, te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta con el código/comandos que uses para lograr esto.

Comment: un detalle a tener siempre en mente: quienes hacen las preguntas tienen el deber y la obligación de traducir sus preguntas, caso contrario serán cerradas por estar ajenos al idioma utilizado en el sitio. Aprecio mucho la buena intención de @Lorthas :D Es muy importante que el usuario Adrian Rojas realice la traducción :D Dale brother! bienvenido al sitio, sigamos las normas y hagamos de este sitio el mejor en todo hispanoamérica :D

Comment: @fredyfx Eso no lo sabía.

Comment: Por cierto Adrian, revisa este enlace: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour así aprenderás a detalle el funcionamiento del sitio :D

Comment: @Lorthas ahora lo sabes hermano :D sigamos haciendo crecer este sitio :D gracias por la buena colaboración que realizas :D

Comment: ok no sabia eso, pero lo tendré en cuenta

Comment: ¿Y qué intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: ya encontré la solución en batch con el comando sed, con esto lo resolví           sed -r 's/("[^",]+),([^"]+")/\1 \2/g'

Answer (score 1):

en lo que busque encontré el comando sed que permite remplazar cadenas por medio de expresiones regulares. en mi solución utilizo una expresión regular para eliminar la coma que se encuentra entre comillas de entrada le paso un archivo de texto y como resultado genero otro archivo de texto.

El código es el siguiente:

```
sed -r 's/("[^",]+),([^"]+")/\1 \2/g' $OutputFolder/$archivo.txt > $OutputFolder/resultado.txt
```